# Crystal report export to rtf and open with word 2013 reduces image proportion(size) and align to left

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

when i export my crystal report 13 to rtf format and then open with ms word 2013 , it seems like the document content and image size getting minimised and aligned to left. I noticed that there is no option for export to word 2013 but to 2003,2007 and some other options, what should i do to overcome my problem. Please help anyone to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem half solved when i change the page layout settings in view to text page ,then the problem happen only when open it in editable option, otherwise the image is ok and can edit with easily.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal is not useable with Office 2013. You should use another reporting tool if you need to embed reports in Word.